# Why is it when my player dies, the whole loop resets?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am working on a game. The code I provided is working properly, but for some reason when I die, the timer resets from the beginning. I have no idea what is causing this problem.

```
local countdownLabel = script.Parent
local intermissionUI = script.Parent.Parent.Parent

local function countdown()
    local counter = 20
    while counter > 0 do
        countdownLabel.Text = tostring(counter)
        counter = counter - 1
        wait(1)
    end
end

local function peaceDown()
    local counter = 30
    while counter > 0 do
        countdownLabel.Text = tostring(counter)
        counter = counter - 1
        wait(1)
    end
end

local function mainCountdown()
    local counter = 270
    while counter > 0 do
        countdownLabel.Text = tostring(counter)
        counter = counter - 1
        wait(1)
    end
end

local function hideUI()
    intermissionUI.ImageLabel.Visible = false 
    wait(10)
    intermissionUI.ImageLabel.Visible = true
end

while true do
    countdown()
    peaceDown()
    mainCountdown()
    hideUI()
end
```

Comment: Is this LocalScript in the StarterGUI?

Comment: It's not a local script, it's a normal script, but it is in a textbox (named Timer), which is in an imagelabel named ImageLabel), which is in a screengui (named IntermissionUI), which in turn is in the StarterGUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some information from the startergui documentation:

> When a Player.Character respawns, the contents of their PlayerGui are
> emptied. Children of the StarterGui are then copied along with their
> descendants into the PlayerGui.

So every time you die a new script is generated replacing the one before. If this script is supposed to run per player you could create a script that uses [Players.PlayerAdded](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Players#PlayerAdded) to add a script to their player folder instead.

If you're planning on having one global countdown you could have a script in serverstorage that updates a global variable in replicated storage that then is accessed by a local script that updates the Label